# Deletar uma linha no Datagrid

Tags: c#, datagridview

Estou tentando excluir a linha em que tem o foco de um `datagrid`, tenho usado o seguinte código:

```
datagrid.Rows.RemoveAt(e.RowIndex);
```

Está retornando a seguinte mensagem:

> Uncommitted new row cannot be deleted.

O que está errado? Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É necessário definir a propriedade [`AllowUserToAddRows`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.allowusertoaddrows%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) do `DataGridView` para *false*.

E para evitar uma exceção [`OutOfRangeException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.argumentoutofrangeexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), verifique antes se o índice da linha é válido.

```
var indice = e.RowIndex;
if (indice >= 0) {
    var linha = dataGridView1.Rows[indice];
    if (!linha.IsNewRow)
        dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(linha);
}
```

Comment: Amigo @Qmechanic73 se eu definir a propriedade AllowUserToAddRows do DataGridView para false. Nenhuma linha irpa aparecer.. Há outro forma. Preciso excluir sempre a última linha do datagrid.

Comment: Usando o Seguinte Código   `dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;var index = e.RowIndex;if (index >= 0){             dgvCompeticao.Rows.RemoveAt(index);}`deu o esse exceção.: **Operation cannot be performed in this event handler.**

Comment: @FabrícioSimoneAlanaMendes Editei e coloquei um outro modo sem precisar mexer em `AllowUserToAddRows`.

Comment: seu códgio ainda está dano erros **Operation cannot be performed in this event handler.**

Comment: @FabrícioSimoneAlanaMendes Tente o seguinte: `BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate { dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(e.RowIndex); }));`.

Comment: @FabrícioSimoneAlanaMendes Uma outra coisa, a propriedade `AllowUserToAddRows` deveria servir para esse caso, quando *false* ela elimina a **última** linha em branco, não dando possibilidade ao usuário adicionar *rows*. Como você está importando os dados? testei aqui inserindo dados dinamicamente e pareceu funcionar bem.

Comment: Estou colocando o código no eventro **CellEnter** Os dados não são importados, ele são digitados, e por isso eu preciso limitar a quantidade linha, que será salva no banco

Comment: @FabrícioSimoneAlanaMendes Conseguiu? Veja se esse [**código**](http://pastebin.com/FKreyCAJ) funciona para o que você pretende fazer.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
private void btoDeleletarItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
datagrid.Rows.RemoveAt(datagrid.CurrentRow.Index);
}
```

Desse modo você estará deletando do DataGrid apenas a linha que estiver selecionada na tabela (Grid). Lembre-se que é bom marcar a opção **SelectionMode** para **FullRowSelect**, para que quando uma célula da linha for selecionada pelo usuário ou por você a linha inteira seja marcada.

Answer (score -1):

Tente isso:

```
if (dgvItens.CurrentRow != null)
        {
            listaItens.RemoveAt(dgvItens.CurrentRow.Index);
            dgvItens.DataSource = listaItens.ToList();
        }
```